# GWT and JSNI add Javascript button into HTML panel

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I create a simple Javascript file containing a simple button.

```
function testfuncion() {
    document.write('<input type="button" name="hello" value="hello">');
}
```

Then I created a HTML panel in gwt.

```
HTML panelHtmlTry = new HTML();
```

How can put the Javascript button into the HTML panel?

In this experiment I can't create the button in gwt but only put a Javascript object into the gwt panel.

PS: i can use html panel or horizzontal panel. My objective is put a javascript button on each GWT panel and show it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Most likely, there is a much simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: i have many .js file (that contains button,text or other object as image , ect) created by other people and i can't modify it , i must create a UI with gwt panel wich add this .js file on gwt panels.

Comment: what about security? does anyone can simply put anything in those script files? what about conflicting scripts? consider simply one more file, identical to the one presented here - the `document.write()` calls will override each other, reconstructing the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure this JS produces HTML? Or there is an HTML file and a JS that works with this HTML? If you can separate HTML from JS (which is always the right way to do it), then the solution is much simpler than what you try.

Comment: yes the js create a simple button i add this button into a GWt panel How can i do?

Comment: YOU ARE HEADING IN THE WRONG DIRECTION ON A ONE WAY STREET!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a simpler way to do what you want. But if you want to do what you want. You can call the custom JavaScript method through JSNI.

This JSNI method calls your custom JS script, which is included in the host page.

```
private native void testfunction() /*-{
  $wnd.testfuncion();
}-*/;
```

$wnd is a reference to the browsers `window` object see [GWT Docs on JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI?hl=de.)

Then you can call this JSNI method anywhere in your GWT code:

```
testfunction();
```

And every time, the JavaScript function from the file gets called through JSNI.

---

You can temporarily redifine document.write, so that it sets the button in the `HTML` widget you wish.

```
private native void testfunction(HTML html) /*-{
  var originalWriteFunc = $wnd.document.write;
  $wnd.document.write = function(str) {
    html.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML::setHTML(Ljava/lang/String;)(str);
  };

  $wnd.testfuncion();
  $wnd.document.write = originalWriteFunc;
}-*/;
```

So you need to call testfunction, with the HTML widget, where the button should be positioned.

Comment: this method override all panel i created with gwt, have other solution?

Comment: this is the behaviour of document.write, you need to insert the button explicitly into an elment by id, or sth. (or where should the button be inserted automatically?)

Comment: i have many html panel in all page but in only one i must insert the javascript button it must insert automatially when i open the page

Comment: see updated answer, you can give in the html widget, where the button should be positioned, although this smells and is clearly no good practice.

Comment: i don't understand I pass into native method a html panel? it' not be the reverse? pass the native method into html panel?

Comment: you could try to set the innerHTML of the HTML widget to the <script src ...> tag, maybe this works so: html.setHTML("<script src foreign-file.js><script...>testfunction();</script>");

Comment: i have many .js file i can't insert javscript code directly in gwt method, my only chance is load a .js file and put on a gwt panel all but i have problem to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Given that no modifications are allowed to the JS file, and assuming the `input` **is the only `input` in the document**, you could extend `HTML` to wrap the `input` element:

```java
public class MyInputHtml extends HTML {

    public MyInputHtml() {

        // initialize DOM with external script content
        testfunction();

        // set the DOM element as the widget's element
        Element body = RootPanel.get().getElement();
        Element el = body.getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0);
        setElement(el);
    }

    private native void testfunction() /*-{
        $wnd.testfuncion();
    }-*/;
}
```

It'll be best, of course, if you assign the `input` with an `id`. That way you can look it up simply by calling `RootPanel.get(id)`, thus avoiding the need for an index based search. This will robust your code, as changes in the DOM won't affect this lookup.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand where i call javascript function?

Comment: you'd have to activate it when constructing this class, see the updated answer.

Comment: i dont attach the javascript panel on rootpanel but into a customize gwt panel (html panel or horizontal panel)

Comment: you can attach it to any panel you wish (e.g. by calling `somePanel.add(MyInputHtml)`, the calls associated with `RootPanel` are there to look up the native `input` element.

Comment: when i compile i receive many error on the class myInputhtml. i don't want attach all to rootpanel i have a panel that is attached on root panel.

Comment: again, in bold text: **you can attach it to any panel you wish**.

Answer (score 0):

Let your testFunction return a string. This you can insert into your panelHtmlTry.

Comment: In my experiment i can't do any modification to javascript file