# Can I put a JavaScript button next to the GWT button?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

Is it possible to create a horizontal panel with 2 buttons, one in `GWT` and one in `JavaScript`?

For example, I have this object:

```
HorizontalPanel panelHeader = new HorizontalPanel();

Button buttonexample = new Button();
```

Now, I have created a `.js` file with the button:

```
function javascriptbutton(){
    document.write('<input type="button" name="try" value="try">');
}
```

and created a `jsni` method to call

```
public native static void javascriptTest() /*-{
    $wnd.javascriptbutton(); // JSNI 
}-*/;
```

My question is: how can I add the `jsni` method that contains a button on horizontal panel? Usually for `GWT`, I do `panelheadr.add(button)`, but how can I do it for a `javascript` button?

Comment: WHY? I am just curious what real world scenario does this serve.

Comment: my scenario is integrate some part of old javascript GUI into a new GWT GUI

Comment: Headsup!! Such low levels of integration is going to be a head ache. its okay to import an odd widget like Color Picker or Date Picker but might not be feasible to mix and match at level of js and gwt buttons!!!

Comment: please remove **[your old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089810/gwt-and-jsni-add-javascript-button-into-html-panel/14090160#14090160)**, as it duplicates the contents of this one, and is obsolete by now.

Comment: note that the method does not *contain* a button, but rather ***writes** a button to the document*. this may give you a hard time scaling that code to add more widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate JS from HTML.

Create both buttons in GWT. Assign an id to your button that needs an external JavaScript. Attach a click handler to your button, and call your native JS from this click handler:

```
myButton.getElement().setId("jsButton");
myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Here you call your JSNI native method
        javascriptTest();
    }

});
```

In your native JS method you can reference this button by its id.

Answer (score 0):

Creating such a simple widget like Button in javascript and using in GWT should be your last resort and tricky as it might cause a cross-browser compatibility issues. In addition it will be difficult if you have to debug that code. Anyway there is a better solution.

Your custom button should be a GWT widget in order to add it to layout containers. That means the button class should implement at least `IsWidget` this allows the layout container which the button will be added to call `asWidget` method and return a simple wrapper container for button which allows you to layout the button easily. The following example uses a SimplePanel as the wrapper.

```
public class MyTextButton implements IsWidget, HasClickHandlers
{
    private SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();
    private Button button;
    public MyTextButton()
    {
        button = Button.create(panel.getElement());
    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget()
    {
        return panel;
    }
    //Use JavaScriptObject to create the DOM element for button which resides in the SimplePanel
    private static class Button extends JavaScriptObject
    {
        private static native Button create(Element parent)/*-{
            //create your javascript button here using parent element as the wrapper.
            //ex: if your function is correct
            //$wnd.javascriptbutton(parent);
        }-*/;
    }

    @Override
    public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler)
    {
        //bind this handler to native button's onClick, return the registration for removal, on remove you need to reset the onClick
        return null;
    }
}
```

But ideally the `MyTextButton` class can be extended by `UIObject` or any other specific class if you want to get built in features.